# Parse the url to other Activity to load PDF from that url

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, url, android-activity

I have two activity's in app. One has 3 buttons and other has PDFView from github "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.1" i am trying to load pdf from url from this code. it works for me

```
public class PDFActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PDFView pdfView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);

        new RetrievePDFStream().execute("my url to load pdf example http://sample.com/xyz.pdf");

    }


    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>
    {

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine, but I have to load another pdf from activity 1 from other url, to change that url "new RetrievePDFStream" when I click button 1 to load another pdf in this activity and button 2 to load another pdf from this activity.

**Any Answers are highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have 3 buttons and two actvities.
In ack1 you have 3 buttons and in ack2 you have pdf viewer. So if i click on ack1 button1 you want to load url1 from ack2 and if i click on ack1 button2 you want to load url2 form ack2 and so on....
If that is the requirement then you can use intent extras.
Form ack1 do this:

```
button1.onclick(new onclicklistener{
   publi void onClick(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ack2.class);
        intent.putExtras("url","pdf url1");
    }}
```

for button2 jst change the "pdf url1" to "pdf url2"
for button3 jst change the "pdf url1" to "pdf url3"

in ack2 do this:
        in onCreate() method:

```
    Intent i=this.getIntent();
    String url=i.getExtras("url");
```

From here you will get url you passed in the first activity based on the button you clicked . If user clicked on button 1 you will get "pdf url1", if he clciked on button2 you will get "pdf url2".. so on...

Edit:code is for reference dont copy &paste it...

Comment: You are welcome. Up vote the answer if it worked. Please search thoroughly before posting a question. I guess this was already been asked.